# Ionic Deep Links route url

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, deeplink, ionic-native

What should be the specified route if my url is 
https://test.fa.dk/avpi/p1/suite/applink/des212321

I use a $cordovaDeepLinks.route('avpi.p1.suite.applink')
It does not work . Can anyone please correct the route ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cordovaDeeplinks.route({
                        '/avpi/p1/suite/applink/:applinkId': {
                            target: '/*/avpi/p1/suite/applink',
                            parent: 'products'
                        }
                    })
```

seems to work.